# Cooperation of threads reader and writers

Tags: java, multithreading, paint

I have a class(I will put it in very simplefied way)

Window is drawing figures while Mover is changing their coordinates(x,y) and I do not want to `Window` read the figure's coordinates while Mover is moving it.

```
class Figure{
int x, int y;
Figure(){...}

  void move(int x, int y){ //when mover is moving by this method
      this.x+=x;
      this.y+=y;
  }
  void draw(Graphics g){ //i do not want this method running
      g.draw(x,y); //I USE x,y here
  }     
}
```

and then I have class `Mover` which modifies `x,y` in `Figure`

```
class Mover extends Thread{
  Figure f;
  Mover(Figure f){
  this.f = f;
  }
     public void run(){
         while(true){f.move(3,4);}
         Thread.sleep(30);

//
      }       
    }
```

and in the end

```
class Window extends JFrame(){
ArrayList<Figure> l;
   public void paint(Graphics g){
      while(true){
        foreach
          l.draw();
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this is by adding the [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) keyword to the `move` and `draw` methods.  This will lock the methods using `this`, so only one will be able to execute at a time (and in addition you won't be able to execute `move` more than once at the same time).

```
class Figure{
    int x, int y;
    Figure(){...}

    public synchronized void move(int x, int y){ //when mover is moving by this method
         this.x+=x;
         this.y+=y;
    }
    public synchronized void draw(Graphics g){ //i do not want this method running
        g.draw(x,y); //I USE x,y here
    }     
}
```

Comment: Could you show it on the code. I have to say I always hated threads and these magic words like synchronize never worked for me well. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure just `synchronized` in the method stub will do the job?

Comment: See my edit.  For what you've described, `synchronized` will do the job - this will lock these methods on `this` so that only one can execute at a time.  You're only accessing `x` and `y` via these methods, so you don't need to do anything special to these variables.